# Power BI - reports embedded, row level security & refresh rate for customers

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

My team plans to build a web platform which gathers data in a DB about different crypto transactions. I am planning to use Power BI to get that data from the db and build some reports which will be embedded into the web platform, reports which will be accessed by users who log in in the web platform.

Is this possible, taking into consideration the following aspects?

1. I want to apply row level security access so that users who log on the web platform will be able to see only data related to them?
2. Should I assign a Power BI Pro license to each user who registers the platform in order to be able to see the data or is there any other solution to this?
3. How often may I set-up data refreshes/updates? 30 minutes?

I am looking to apply row level security access and have users access the reports based on their web platfrom login credentials. Hopefully this is possible. I read something about Power BI Report for Customers using App Owns Data. Is this the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the App Owns Data, you will be building a portal on top of an embedded capacity. I assume that you will be using an ['A' Sku](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-capacity).

> I want to apply row level security access so that users who log on the
> web platform will be able to see only data related to them?

Yes you can use RLS to control what users see what data, in an embedded context . (See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security))

> Should I assign a Power BI Pro license to each user who registers the
> platform in order to be able to see the data or is there any other
> solution to this?

No, you don't need a PBI Pro license for each user for your platform, this is handled by the capacity. You'll only need Pro for those who are developing the reports. Your other users, handled by your web portal will be 'read only'.

> How often may I set-up data refreshes/updates? 30 minutes?

You can set up the report schedule as normal in the portal, up to 48 times per day with a capacity based Power BI Dataset.

I would take a look at the MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/) for more details on the what embedded can do, and also capacity planning for your users.